# Is there a way to access information from behind a dropdown menu with requests in python?

Tags: python, html, drop-down-menu, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrap some information off of a website that has a dropdown menu and once you click one of the options it brings you to a new page with the same link and I am unsure of how to get to this information with the requests library.
here is the HTML of the dropdown.
Would love some help
Thank you!

```html
<ul class="list"><li data-value="" class="option selected focus">Select a Market</li><li data-value="Show All" class="option">Show All</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6" class="option">US - S&amp;P 500 Index</li><li data-value="5a2b420decfdc711085dc51d" class="option">Bitcoin Per USD</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfeb" class="option">US - Dow Jones Industrials Index</li><li data-value="5a8e2222ecfdc7197c27d1a3" class="option">US - CBOE VIX Index</li><li data-value="5653923cc7eb6e355878c00d" class="option">US Dollar Index (Cash)</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf37" class="option">NY Gold Futures</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878beb4" class="option">NY Crude Oil Futures</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878beb1" class="option">NY Natural Gas Futures</li><li data-value="5653922fc7eb6e355878bed6" class="option">Canadian Dollar Spot</li><li data-value="5653922cc7eb6e355878be8c" class="option">Wheat CBT Futures</li><li data-value="5ff35e7a54e89812b492df70" class="option">Uranium Spot Per Pound</li><li data-value="56539230c7eb6e355878beda" class="option">Euro Adjusted Spot</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf36" class="option">NY Copper Futures</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf32" class="option">NY Platinum Futures</li><li data-value="5653922cc7eb6e355878be93" class="option">Soybeans CBT Futures</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf34" class="option">NY Silver COMEX Futures</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bff3" class="option">US - PHLX Gold/Silver Index</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfc9" class="option">US - Oil &amp; Gas Stock Index</li><li data-value="5653922cc7eb6e355878be9e" class="option">Corn (CBOT)</li><li data-value="5a8e221fecfdc7197c27d189" class="option">Global - MSCI World $ Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221eecfdc7197c27d186" class="option">Global - MSCI Emerging Markets $ Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221eecfdc7197c27d184" class="option">Global - MSCI All Country World $ Index</li><li data-value="5a8e2221ecfdc7197c27d19a" class="option">Europe - EURO STOXX 50 Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221aecfdc7197c27d15d" class="option">US - NASDAQ 100 Index</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878c005" class="option">US - NASDAQ Composite Index</li><li data-value="5c3ee86f2bbac10948c4c48c" class="option">US - Russell 1000 Index</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfcd" class="option">US - Russell 2000 Index</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfec" class="option">US - Dow Jones Utilities Index</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfda" class="option">Canada - S&amp;P/TSX Composite Index</li><li data-value="5a8e2220ecfdc7197c27d196" class="option">Canada - S&amp;P / TSE 60 Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221fecfdc7197c27d18c" class="option">US - New York Stock Exchange Composite Index</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878c003" class="option">Mexico - IPC Index</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe9" class="option">Germany - DAX Index</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe3" class="option">France - CAC-40 Index</li><li data-value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfef" class="option">UK - FTSE 100 Index</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfc8" class="option">Spain - IBEX 35 Index</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878c007" class="option">Japan - NIKKEI Tokyo Index</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878c000" class="option">South Korea - KOSPI 200 Index</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfd0" class="option">China - Shanghai Composite</li><li data-value="56539239c7eb6e355878bfd1" class="option">China - Shenzhen Composite</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878bff6" class="option">Hong Kong - Hang Seng Cash Share Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221fecfdc7197c27d18b" class="option">India - Nifty 50 Index</li><li data-value="5653923bc7eb6e355878bffa" class="option">India - S&amp;P BSE SENSEX Index</li><li data-value="5a8e221aecfdc7197c27d15f" class="option">Russia - Micex Index</li><li data-value="56539230c7eb6e355878bedb" class="option">Japanese Yen Spot</li><li data-value="5653922fc7eb6e355878bed5" class="option">British Pound Spot</li><li data-value="5653922fc7eb6e355878bed4" class="option">Australian Dollar Spot</li><li data-value="5653922ec7eb6e355878bec3" class="option">New Zealand Dollar</li><li data-value="56539230c7eb6e355878bedc" class="option">Swiss Franc Spot</li><li data-value="5653922ec7eb6e355878becc" class="option">Brazil Real Spot</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878bebd" class="option">Chinese Yuan Spot</li><li data-value="56539230c7eb6e355878bee5" class="option">Mexico Peso Spot</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878beba" class="option">Russian Rubles Spot</li><li data-value="5653923fc7eb6e355878c073" class="option">South African Rand</li><li data-value="5653922fc7eb6e355878bed2" class="option">Hong Kong Dollar Spot</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878bebc" class="option">Turkish Lira Spot</li><li data-value="5653922ec7eb6e355878bec5" class="option">Singapore Dollar Spot</li><li data-value="5653922ec7eb6e355878bec6" class="option">South Korean Won Spot</li><li data-value="5b5b72237be3b20794c6dc51" class="option">US BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b721e7be3b20794c6dc0c" class="option">Canada BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b721e7be3b20794c6dc18" class="option">Euro BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b72237be3b20794c6dc4e" class="option">UK BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b721d7be3b20794c6dc03" class="option">Germany BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b72207be3b20794c6dc2c" class="option">Japan BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b72207be3b20794c6dc29" class="option">Italy BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b721e7be3b20794c6dc15" class="option">Spain BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b721c7be3b20794c6dbfd" class="option">Australia BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="5b5b72207be3b20794c6dc32" class="option">Mexico BMK 10 Yr Index</li><li data-value="56539237c7eb6e355878bf9e" class="option">Gld Miners</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf30" class="option">NY Palladium Futures</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878bea9" class="option">US CBT 10 Year T-Notes</li><li data-value="5653922dc7eb6e355878bec2" class="option">Norwegian Krone Spot</li><li data-value="5c4171982bbac1517cff4b0b" class="option">US - iShares China Large-Cap ETF</li><li data-value="5653923cc7eb6e355878c018" class="option">US - United States Oil Fund LP</li><li data-value="5c41719c2bbac1517cff4b39" class="option">US - SPDR S&amp;P Oil &amp; Gas Exploration &amp; Production ETF</li><li data-value="5c41719b2bbac1517cff4b2e" class="option">US - Financial Select Sector SPDR Fund</li><li data-value="5c41719b2bbac1517cff4b2d" class="option">US - Energy Select Sector SPDR Fund</li><li data-value="5c41719c2bbac1517cff4b38" class="option">US - SPDR S&amp;P Oil &amp; Gas Equipment &amp; Services ETF</li><li data-value="56539232c7eb6e355878bf0b" class="option">US - Chevron Corporation</li><li data-value="5653923dc7eb6e355878c03e" class="option">US - Alphabet, Inc - Google C shares </li><li data-value="56539231c7eb6e355878bef7" class="option">US - Tesla Motors</li><li data-value="5e9f388054e898058c527d96" class="option">CA - Vermilion Energy Inc</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf44" class="option">Ur Energy NC</li><li data-value="56539237c7eb6e355878bf95" class="option">US - Freeport-McMoRan</li><li data-value="5653923ec7eb6e355878c060" class="option">US - NetFlix Inc.</li><li data-value="6011ffa954e898481c0ca143" class="option">US - Gamestop</li><li data-value="5ec2bae254e8982e6ca74a47" class="option">US - AMC Inc. </li><li data-value="5c4171ab2bbac1517cff4ba5" class="option">US - Under Armour - Class A</li><li data-value="5c4171a62bbac1517cff4b85" class="option">US - Qualcomm</li><li data-value="56539232c7eb6e355878bf17" class="option">US - General Electric</li><li data-value="5653923ec7eb6e355878c050" class="option">UK - Royal Dutch Shell</li><li data-value="56539233c7eb6e355878bf27" class="option">US - Marathon Oil</li><li data-value="5a8e2223ecfdc7197c27d1b0" class="option">US - PHLX Oil Service Index</li><li data-value="5653923cc7eb6e355878c01a" class="option">US - Invesco QQQ Trust</li><li data-value="56539231c7eb6e355878befb" class="option">US - Amazon</li><li data-value="56539234c7eb6e355878bf63" class="option">Suncor</li><li data-value="56539230c7eb6e355878bee8" class="option">US - ExxonMobil</li><li data-value="56539235c7eb6e355878bf73" class="option">Agnico Eagle Mines Limited</li><li data-value="56539238c7eb6e355878bfc0" class="option">Mcewen Min</li><li data-value="56539235c7eb6e355878bf68" class="option">Teck</li><li data-value="56539236c7eb6e355878bf84" class="option">Cameco</li><li data-value="5c4171ad2bbac1517cff4bb5" class="option">Canadian Residential Real Estate Index</li><li data-value="5c4171ae2bbac1517cff4bc6" class="option">US Residential Real Estate Index</li></ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: its a password-protected website  but here: https://www.ask-socrates.com/Watchlist

Comment: Basically the information I'm looking for isn't loaded until you select an option from the dropdown menu and I'm not sure how to simulate that with requests.